# Define shared path parameter that can be re-used by multiple paths with Swagger

Tags: yaml, swagger

I've got a series of paths that use the same path parameter:

```
paths:
  /catalog/items/{id}:
    ...
  /catalog/items/{id}/children:
    ...
  etc.
```

I would like the {id} parameter to be defined once with a description and type so that I can reuse it, but this appears to be invalid:

```
paths:
   ...
parameters:
  catalogItemId: # <-- Not a valid parameter definition
    name: id
    in: path 
    description: The ID of the catalog item to update.
    required: false
    type: integer
    format: int64
```

It doesn't *seem* like this should be invalid according to the schema linked by the editor (http://swagger.io/v2/schema.json#), but for some reason this is rejected by the online editor.

Is there anyway to share path parameter definitions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly after posting this I realized that the path parameter was listed as

```
required: false
```

Path parameters MUST be required for Swagger API definitions.  Changing that to `true` fixed everything up.  It's just a side effect of the way the schema validation occurs that causes a non descriptive error to get dumped out.